# Setting optimizeminimize options

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

In https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization it states using `-p` to make it use UglifyJS.  But it does not indicate how to set the [options for UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2). e.g. `semicolons`

Please note it should only do the uglify on `-p` not every build

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
As you might aware that `-p` is nothing but the production shortcut for [`--optimize-minimize --optimize-occurrence-order`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/cli#production-shortcut--p). If webpack find a config file in current directory, it takes the `UglifyJsPlugin` configuration from the config file.

And when you wanted to add a configuration only in production mode, you could do like,

```
> NODE_ENV=production webpack -p

var config = {
     /*... other configs ... */
   }


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            output: { 
                 beautify: true, 
                 quote_style : 2, 
                 semicolons: false /* default: true  */
            } 
        })
    )
} 

module.exports = config
```

If you have `webpack.config.js` file, you can add the `UglifyJsPlugin` as shown below with the options you want. The `semicolons` option is part of `output` option.

```
plugins: [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
         output: { 
             beautify: true, 
             quote_style : 2, 
             semicolons: false /* default: true  */
         } 
      })]
```

Comment: but I only want it to occur when I do `-p` not all the time.  Anyway I'll check it out.... and confirmed it does it with or without -p